# Have a constructor with inputs added to array

Tags: c#, arrays, class, constructor

I have a class with a constructor, and want to use that class in an array. However trying gives an error. This is my code:

```cs
using System;

class ClassA {
    public ClassA(int a, int b) {}
}
class MainClass {
    void Main(string[] Args) {
        ClassA[] ClassArray = new ClassA(1,2)[3];
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
ClassA[] ClassArray = new ClassA(1,2)[3];
```

Do

```
ClassA[] ClassArray = new ClassA [] {new ClassA(2, 3), . . . . };
```

OR

```
ClassA[] ClassArray = new ClassA[3];
ClassArray[0] = new ClassA(2, 3); 
ClassArray[1] = new ClassA(2, 3);
ClassArray[2] = new ClassA(2, 3);
```

Comment: Could you use a for loop for the second method? Also thanks.

Comment: @AteurGames Defintely - `for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) array[i] = new MyClass();`